# loop user inputted string in script

Tags: bash, user-input

trying to make a basic addition function that adds the numbers entered and outputs a total. Here's my current function:

```
function addition() {
    read -a arr

    for i in ${arr[@]}
    do
        str=$str'+'$i

        echo $i
    done

    echo $str
}
```

but this seems to ask for one input then outputs the above. I've also tried using:

```
function addition() {
    for i in ${input[@]}
```

but that outputs an empty string. How do I go about creating a function that takes this command:

```
$ addition 4 3 13 40
```

into the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your script/function takes the numbers on the command line, then you don't need to read them with `read` (which reads from standard input).

Instead:

```
addition () {
    sum=0

    for number do
        sum=$(( sum + number ))
    done

    printf 'Sum is %d\n' "$sum"
}
```

The loop could also be written more explicitly as

```
for number in "$@"; do
    sum=$(( sum + number ))
done
```

In both variations of the loop, the `number` variable will be assigned the value of each positional parameter ("command line argument") in turn, and the body of the loop will add these to the `sum` variable.

Note that the above code assumes that all command line arguments are integers without verifying that they are.

---

For fancier output:

```
addition () {
    sum=0

    for number do
        sum=$(( sum + number ))
    done

    ( IFS='+'; printf '%s = %d\n' "$*" "$sum" )
}
```

`"$*"` will expand to a single string consisting of the positional parameters concatenated with the first character of `$IFS` as delimiter.

Testing:

```
$ addition 1 2 3 90 32
1+2+3+90+32 = 128
```